# Load Java class file on the fly

Tags: java

In one of my ongoing application I want to load java class file to the application when it runs. This particular java file is generated by the user and I don't know the name of that file. but I know the structure of that file (methods, variables , etc.) and location of that file. I know how to load java file using ClassLoader but for this instance it doesn't useful since I don't know the file name. so how do I load java file to my application and access it's method (These user generated java files are stored in one folder so it is ok to load all the java files at once) 
Thanks!

Comment: `File.listFiles()`, then load the files using the `ClassLoader`

Answer (score 1):

Use an [`URLClassLoader`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URLClassLoader.html).

Answer (score 0):

It appears you need to create your own ClassLoader.

Try reading this:

- http://onjava.com/pub/a/onjava/2005/01/26/classloading.html
- http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-dyn0429/

Answer (score -1):

If you know the directory the file is in, you can search it to find the class and use the ClassLoader to load it.